# unique_ptr<map<int, unique_ptr<Value>>> vs. unique_ptr<map<int, Value>>

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Working on a unique_ptr fix where I need to pass a unique_ptr of map to some function as argument.

If we define a `unique_ptr` of map through `std::make_unique`, do we also need to declare the Value of the map as a `unique_ptr` type also?

Or we don't need to do that, as long as we define a `unique_ptr` of map in the heap, then we can populate the map values through stack variable and the map can hold the copies of these stack variables throughout all its lifetime in heap until the owner destroy this map?

like this:

```
auto heap_map = std::make_unique<std::map<
  int,
  std::unique_ptr<Value>>>();
    
(*heap_map)[1] = Value(arg1, arg2);
(*heap_map)[2] = Value(arg1, arg3);
```

Or we have to do it like this:

```
auto heap_map = std::make_unique<std::map<
  int,
  std::unique_ptr<Value>>>();

(*heap_map)[1] = std::make_unique<Value>(arg1, arg2);
(*heap_map)[2] = std::make_unique<Value>(arg1, arg3);
```

Please shed some light regarding the difference between these two use cases above.

Comment: Begs the question why a pointer to `map` in the first place?

Comment: One `unique_ptr` does not imply or force another `unique_ptr`. You use `uniqiue_ptr` on a case-by-case basis where it makes sense to do so. The only things that matter are "do you need a dynamic allocation?" and if yes, "Does `unique_ptr` describe the ownership of the allocation?" Your question doesn't provide enough information for us to help you make those decisions. I suspect you don't need dynamic allocation, because typically with a Standard Library container you don't.

Comment: *"the map can hold these stack values"* -- a map never contains what you call "stack values". Rather, it contains copies of them, stored wherever the map decides they should be stored.

Comment: Please explain why `map<int, Value>` is not the only thing you're using. Is `Value` part of an inheritance hierarchy with `virtual` functions? The outermost `unique_ptr` is probably just adding noise to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you have a map, or a std::unique_ptr to a map.
The real issue here is how to fill the unique_ptr entries in the map.

```
// create the unique_ptr
auto ptr = std::make_unique<Value>(arg1,arg2);

// use the insert function instead of[]
// and unique pointers need to be moved (which will reset ptr)
// so do not use that after this call
heap_map->insert({0,std::move(ptr)});
```