# Use unique pointer or stack variable as class member?

Tags: c++

Assume we have two classes `A` and `B`. By design, `A`’s object will be dynamically allocated through make_unique.

The class `B` will be one of the class member of `A`. should I use `std::unique_ptr` of `B` in `A` or just define a normal variable of `B` in `A`?

```
class B {};

class A {
  A(std::uniqur_ptr<B> b_ptr) : b_(move(b_ptr)) {}

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
};
```

or

```
class B {};

class A {
  A(const B& b) : b_(b) {}

 private:
  B b_;
};
```

just want to know the difference of above snippets.

Comment: As described, I don't see a reason to use a `unique_ptr<B>` instead of a `B`. Is `B` supposed to be an interface with different concrete implementations and `A` is supposed to be able to support any of them? If `B` is just some concrete class, a `unique_ptr` is probably totally unnecessary.

Comment: In the absence of other information, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). What reason do you have to introduce additional complexity? If you don't have one, don't do it. (If you do have one, the question needs more information.)

Comment: Note that, just as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778467/unique-ptrmapint-unique-ptrvalue-vs-unique-ptrmapint-value), it is irrelevant to know how the container (objects of type `A` in this question) is allocated. The statement *"`A`’s object will be dynamically allocated through make_unique"* should have no bearing on the design of `A` (perhaps with some obscure exceptions, maybe after intense performance analysis, but the vast majority of the time, no bearing). That statement is just noise in this question.

Comment: One difference is that the unique ptr can legally be null. Also, there's potential for `b_` to be allocated somewhere significantly different. Leaving access open to incurring a cache miss. Another difference is that the unique ptr can support derived types (if you ever ended up with class C inheriting B. Then your first example would support it, the second would not.

Comment: In addition to @George's comment, if the default constructor `B()` is private or if `B() = delete`, then you should use the `unique_ptr`. If none of the exceptions analysed here are met, then just use the normal object definition (your second case).

Comment: @Maf what you just described would be better suited to `std::optional`, not `std::unique_ptr`. Nullability does not need to require heap allocations. Semantically, an `optional` is more correct in such a case.

Comment: Hi @George, for second example, if A’s object is dynamically created through make_unique, then can I say _b is also created in the heap space even though it just got copied from a stack variable ?

Comment: @JoJo Yes, sort of. The standardese terminology would be that _b is dynamically allocated. The difference is that _b is allocated as part of A's object. Instead of a pointer being allocated as part of A's object with the object of B being allocated separately.

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you explained why you think it is significant to state *"`A`’s object will be dynamically allocated through make_unique."* Or maybe a new question that focuses on that. I think you have a major misunderstanding here, but I have not yet been able to pinpoint it.

Comment: Another use (of `std::unique_ptr`) would be the `pimpl` idiom or other cases where you want to hide the implementation (to reduce compile-time dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

As @eerorika said, storing it directly as a member variable is often a better default to go to.

`std::unique_ptr` is used to denote unique ownership (e.g. the class using this "owns" the memory at that location) -- but ordinarily this is only used when necessary for technical reasons. To name a few such technical reasons:

- You need polymorphic behavior, but also need your class to own the object. In such a case, you would be using a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` to use virtual-dispatch to call functions from the underlying `Derived` instances. You can't store a value of type `Base` and get polymorphic behavior, so it has to be done indirectly by either a reference or a pointer. `std::unique_ptr` makes this possible *while conveying the ownership semantics*.
- You have a class that is extremely large, or costly to copy/move. For example, if you have a data member of `std::array<int,100000>` -- you may not want to have to copy that around directly. However, a `std::unique_ptr` will instead use indirection while allowing for the object to be constructed once and passed in (no penalty for copying)
- You have a class that is uncopyable and immovable, but you would like to make the owning class copy or movable. For example, you may have a `std::mutex` internally -- but you may want to permit moving. In such a case you may have either `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>` or, better yet, an internal `struct` held by a `unique_ptr` so that moving is a cheap and easy operation (since now it only moves pointers).
- You need the data to outlive the class. Dynamic lifetimes allow lifetimes that are irrespective of scopes, and in some cases, this can be necessary if you want the inner workings of a class to be kept alive outside the normal scope of that class.

There are plenty of reasons where a `std::unique_ptr` is the "right" choice, but these are the most common ones that come to mind. There is also `std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr` used for sharing, which has similar justifications to above, but matters when ownership needs to be distributed across multiple objects.

In either case, the determination always comes down to the technical reasons/requirements for your class. In your minimal example, `class B{}` is empty, so it doesn't make sense to use `std::unique_ptr` here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on details of the use case. But, a "normal" member variable is a reasonable default to choose when you have no particular reason to need indirection that the pointer provides.

I would start with the following definition for `A`:

```
struct A {
    B b;
};
```